# Authoryear style and how to make entries appear as Author:Year in the footnotes?

Tags: biblatex

In the authoryear style, how to make the entries appear in the Author:Year format in the footnotes?

Comment: Could you please post a minimal, yet complete, code reproducing the problem?

Comment: `\DeclareDelimFormat[footcite]{nameyeardelim}{\addcolon}` (untested, but something like this should work).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be enough to just redefine the delimiter format for `nameyeardelim` in the appropriate contexts (`footcite` and probably also `smartcite`)

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear, autocite=footnote]{biblatex}

\DeclareDelimFormat[smartcite,footcite]{nameyeardelim}{\addcolon}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson}
ipsum \autocite{worman}
dolor \footcite{nussbaum}
sit \textcite{geer}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Sigfridsson and Ryde:1998.]